# Add columns from different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is my original table. I would like to insert `TempAvg` between 1995 and 1997 for all dates of the year.

This data has the same day and month but different year. See details in image below:

[image: tables and output]

Comment: It is **NOT** okay to post images of your data like this. It makes it so much harder for us to help you, which makes it much less likely you'll get a good answer. Also, the `Output` image doesn't show enough detail for us to infer what you need.

Comment: And what's data versus original fields?

Comment: Don't store dates as separate day/month/year fields, use the `date` data type.

Comment: I recommend you read the help section on [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For database questions it's important to include the data types of your table fields.

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to plus these data not add.

Answer (score 0):

For your SELECT statement you can ignore the day/month in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT [day], [month], [TempTarget]
FROM YourTable
WHERE [year] = 1995
OR [year] = 1997
ORDER BY [month], [day]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, you have temperature data for two years (1995 and 1997) and you want to know the difference of the average temperature on each day of those years.

I don't know why you are **adding** the two average temperatures as shown in your diagram as the title of your field implies you want the **difference**, which would mean subtracting one from the other, but I'll use the calculation from your picture.

You don't say if the data is in the same table, or in separate tables, so I'll assume it's in the same table, which means you need derived tables which you join on day/month:

```
SELECT data1.Day, data1.Month, data1.TempAvg + data2.TempAvg as TempAvgDiff
FROM
  (SELECT Day, Month, TempAvg FROM data WHERE Year = 1995) as data1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Day, Month, TempAvg FROM data WHERE Year = 1997) as data2
ON data1.Day = data2.Day AND data1.Month = data2.Month
```

If you have the data in separate tables, replace the derived tables `data1` and `data2` with the names of your two tables. You'll also have to put the field names `day`, `month` and `year` in quotes or brackets because they are key words in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The output in the picture is summing the TempAvg column across different years and labelling it 'TempAvgDiff'.  It seems you're looking for something like this

```
select [Day], [Month], sum(TempAvg) TempAvgDiff
from TableWithTemps
where [Year] between 1995 and 1997
group by [Day], [Month]
order by [Day], [Month];
```